# Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found

Tags: php, phpunit, pear

I am using XAMPP 1.8.1, Windows 7 64 bit, Netbeans IDE 7.4
I have installed PHPUnit.
When I run a code, I am getting the below error.

> Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\PHPUnit\index.php on line 6

The Code is:

```
<?php

class StackTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testPushAndpop() {
        $stack = array();
        $this->assertEquals(0, count($stack));

        array_push($stack, 'foo');
        $this->assertEquals('foo', $stack[count($stack) - 1]);
        $this->assertEquals(1, count($stack));

        $this->assertEquals('foo', array_pop($stack));
        $this->assertEquals(0, count($stack));
    }

}

?>
```

I have added **D:\xampp\php** in environment variable PATH
Anyone suggest me how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to run the test in a web browser? This confused me for a while. PHPUnit tests are written to be run on the command line.

Answer (score 8):

For new PHPUnit versions you need to extend the `TestCase` only instead of `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` with the help of the use `use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;`

**Old and Depricated Way:**

```
// No namespace in this old method

class ClassATest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

}
```

**New Way adopted in Versions like 6.x:**

```
// Namespace used in this new method

use PHPunit\Framework\TestCase;

class ClassATest extends TestCase {

}
```

If you are not using this new method you'll be getting the difficulties. Adopt it and this will fix your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't mentioned which version of PHP you are using, but if it is 3.5 or higher, just add

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';
```

To the top of your code to pull in the required files.

If not,use:

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php';
```

It's unlikely that you're using a version earlier than 3.5, but I've included that just in case.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just have to get the latest version of PHPUnit and not include any file as mentioned below. This worked for me when I upgraded to latest version but was running old Unit tests which had:

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php';
```

Removing this line fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For those arriving here after updating phpunit to version 6 released.
You will need to rename the class like: 
`\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` to `\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`

Answer (score 0):

There are two levels of answers to this.

The first problem, for some, is that, while class names are case-insentive in PHP, the autoloader sometimes is not, so you **will** need to use the correct name of the parent class: `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`

The second problem is an incompatibility of [PHPUnit 6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48232992/2171120) with itself. If you, like many others, need to be able to write testcases that work with either version, create a new include file with the following content:

```
<?php

if (!class_exists('PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase') &&
  class_exists('\\PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestCase')) {
    abstract class PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {
    }
}
```

Then, include this file at the top of each testcase. The testcases themselves continue to inherit from the aforementioned class, for example, in code of mine:

```
class Minijson_Tests extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
```

Contrary to earlier advice, including `PHPUnit/Autoload.php` or `PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php` has proven to be unnecessary with both PHPUnit 4.2.6 (Debian jessie) and 6.5.5 (Debian sid). It’s also not necessary to write a `phpunit.xml`, `bootstrap.php`, etc. as included in similar advice.